# Let $T$ and $S$ be linear mappings. show that $ST$ is neither one one nor onto.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T$ and $S$ be linear mappings from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, respectively. Show that $ST$ is neither one one nor onto.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Edited my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is never surjective because its image has dimension at most $2$, and so $ST$ is not surjective, because the image of $ST$ is contained in the image of $S$.

$T$ is never injective because its kernel has dimension at least $1$, and so $ST$ is not injective, because the kernel of $ST$ contains the kernel of $T$.

Both claims follow directly from the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Would you please elaborate the logic behind this. Which theorem you have applied for both the cases.

Comment: please elaborate a bit more.